# Lines behind image (top and bottom)

Tags: html, css

I have a centered image on my website, where i need a top and bottom line.
The catch here, is that i need both lines 1px in behind the image, so that they are "align" in top and bottom of the image. I tried using box-shadow but it doesn't work in IE8 (i know it's terrible).

Anyone who has a answer and dying to tell me?

A quick UPDATE to show you my issue:
I'm using bootstrap 2 and displaying a carousel for images. And when there are only one image, the line should be visible. It need to be able to run in IE8 for the customer.

Image example:

http://postimg.org/image/xi3eurm81/

My example with shadow-box is here:

Html:

```
 <div id="artist-carousel">

    <div class="simple-carousel-window">

            <div class="simple-carousel-rail">
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 3 * Model.Images.Count; i++) // times 3 due to infinite scrolling
                    {
                        var index = i % Model.Images.Count;
                    <div class="simple-carousel-div" data-index="@(i)" data-link="@Model.NativeImages[index]">
                        <a class="element">
                            <img  src="@Model.Images[index]" />
                        </a>
                        <a class="fullsize">
                            <img src="~/content/images/carousel-fullsize.png" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                        if (Model.Images.Count <= 2 && i >= 0) { break; }
                    }
                }
            </div>
            @if (Model.Images.Count >= 3)
            {
                <a class="simple-carousel-prev" href="#" data-slide="prev">
                    <img src="~/content/images/carousel-left.png" /></a>
                <a class="simple-carousel-next" href="#" data-slide="next">
                    <img src="~/content/images/carousel-right.png" /></a>

            }

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.simple-carousel-window {
    width: 820px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px -2px #ebebeb, inset 0 -2px 2px -2px #ebebeb;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    .simple-carousel-rail {
        font-size: 0;
    }

    .simple-carousel-prev {
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 10px;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .simple-carousel-next {
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        right: 10px;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .simple-carousel-div {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        .element {
            img {
                height: 360px;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        .fullsize {
            display: block;
            opacity: 0.5;
            position: absolute;

            // centering image
            top: 150px;
            margin-left: -85px; 
            left: 50%;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your code that you have written so far. That helps others to help you.

Comment: i have no clue what you mean, and why do u need ie8 compatibility?

Comment: An example image might also be useful.. have you tried using `border-top` and `border-bottom`?

Comment: @Wezly - yes it doesn't work either because it just sets the line above the image and not 1px under the image.

Comment: I think an example Image is required.

Comment: @Wezly Here you go http://postimg.org/image/xi3eurm81/ - This is the example with box-shadow which won't work in my case unfortunately.

Comment: I think you better have an example running in jsfiddle or codepen from there we can try to help you out straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CXKrh/

### HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 98px;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
div > img {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

The idea is that the height of the container = image height - border width (top and bottom)

We then apply a negative margin to the images to "bump" the image back over the border.

Comment: Thank you gvee - Just what I needed!